# Conditionally copy files in multistage dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, copy

I need to copy files from previous docker stage and from base folder of Dockerfile. This is my COPY

```
COPY if [ "$BASE_IMAGE" = "external" ] ; then COPY --from=BUILD $TMP_LOCATION/*.properties $DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION \
               ; COPY --from=BUILD $TMP_LOCATION/*.xml $DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION \
               ; COPY standalone.conf /opt/wildfly/bin ; fi
```

getting `#6 0.410 /bin/sh: COPY: command not found` . Please find my Dockerfile

```
#########
# BUILD #
#########

ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11 AS BUILD
RUN mkdir /opt/trunk
RUN mkdir /opt/tmp
WORKDIR /opt/trunk
RUN --mount=target=/root/.m2,type=cache
RUN --mount=source=.,target=/opt/trunk,type=bind,rw mvn clean package && cp -r /opt/trunk/out/app.ear /opt/tmp

##################
# Dependencies #
##################

FROM $BASE_IMAGE
ARG IMAGE_TYPE
ENV DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/app.ear
ENV TMP_LOCATION /opt/tmp/app.ear

ARG BASE_IMAGE
            
COPY if [ "$BASE_IMAGE" = "external" ] ; then COPY --from=BUILD $TMP_LOCATION/*.properties $DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION \
               ; COPY --from=BUILD $TMP_LOCATION/*.xml $DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION \
               ; COPY standalone.conf /opt/wildfly/bin ; fi
```

Comment: Ah, here is where you asked the same thing that was (is) blocked on the Docker forum. Please be patient to see if you get a response here.

Comment: @Arjan sure, but this is very important for me todo.

Comment: Then please at least add links to the other places where you asked the same thing, so people don't waste time with responses you may have received already? I've edited and approved https://forums.docker.com/t/conditionally-copy-files-in-multistage-dockerfile/111750 now. Success!

Comment: Thanks a lot, let's see if i get a solution!!